# New Ubuntu 17.10 Settings...Add Printer Failed

Tags: networking, printing, samba, hp, raspberrypi

[edit to reformat per suggestion to question - answer]

I recently built a new computer and installed Ubuntu 17.10 on it.  I tried to add the existing network printer (this is a regular HP Laserjet 3050 that is networked via Raspberry PI server, and is in use by multiple other computers on my network RPI).  All of my other computers, which migrated to 17.10 from earlier version (most were probably 17.10, but not all), were able to print no problem, as the existing setup continued to work.

When I attempted to add the networked printer via Settings-Devices-Printers-Add, it would show my network RPI printer, but it would fail with the error message that 'additional packages required'.  But no further information.

Answer (score 1):

It had been a long time since I had set up the other printers, and couldn't remember if a SAMBA client was needed or not, so I did smbclient -L  and it failed with 'not installed'. So I sudo apt install smbclient and repreformed the add printer (along with the 3050 CUPS printer driver in the dropdown), and everything worked!

[not able to click answer checkmark for two days per info]

Comment: I confirm that this did work on Ubuntu 18.04 as well, for a HP ColorLaserjet 4700 printer.